# How to Detect Anonymity of Proxy?

Tags: proxy, anonymous, socks, anonymity

When adding a HTTP Proxy within my Firefox Options panel, I have noticed sometimes when Querying google for *My Ip* the result would return my real IP, whilst other times it would return the Ip of the Proxy I applied.

When obtaining a Proxy they are mostly assigned a type which is commonly refered to as

- Elite *(webserver cannot detect you are using a proxy)*
- Anonymous *(Web server can detect you are using a proxy but not your real IP)*
- Transparent *(web server can find your real ip)*

After doing some research I have found that some proxies send/apply the following headers

```
HTTP_CLIENT_IP:
HTTP_FORWARDED:
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: 11.11.11.11:62728
HTTP_VIA:
HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION:
```

When browsing with a Proxy applied, I have tried to search my headers using Firefox Extention LiveHttpHeaders, but I am unable to see any of the following headers - yet Google is able to detect my real IP.

How can I search for these headers?

Comment: If a proxy adds the X_FORWARDED_FOR header, then the remote server will be able to tell your IP address from it. That's exactly what this header is for, and why anonymous proxies will not add it. Your Firefox extension looks at the request before the proxy has modified it, so there will not be an X_FORWARDED_FOR header for you to see. You'll need to look at the headers as they arrive on the remote server, for example via the URL that @mti2935 suggested.

Answer (score 0):

With your proxy applied, point your browser to http://request.urih.com/.  This page will show all of the headers in the HTTP request, including those that you copied in your question if they are there.